# SUM items in an Array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

How do I sum the second (value[1]) element in this array using `$.each()`?

```
{"dataset":{"id":123643,"dataset_code":"MSACSR","database_code":"FRED","name":"Monthly Supply of Houses in the United States","description":"Months' Supply Seasonally Adjusted, The months' supply is the ratio of houses for sale to houses sold. This statistic provides an indication of the size of the for sale inventory in relation to the number of houses currently being sold. The months' supply indicates how long  the current for sale inventory would last given the current sales rate if no additional new houses were built. ","refreshed_at":"2018-07-29T02:49:52.644Z","newest_available_date":"2018-06-01","oldest_available_date":"1963-01-01","column_names":["Date","Value"],"frequency":"monthly","type":"Time Series","premium":false,"limit":null,"transform":null,"column_index":null,"start_date":"1963-01-01","end_date":"2018-06-01","data":[["2018-06-01",5.7],["2018-05-01",5.3],["2018-04-01",5.6],["2018-03-01",5.3],["2018-02-01",5.4],["2018-01-01",5.6],["2017-12-01",5.5],["2017-11-01",4.9],["2017-10-01",5.6],["2017-09-01",5.3],["2017-08-01",6.0],["2017-07-01",6.0],["2017-06-01",5.3],["2017-05-01",5.4],["2017-04-01",5.4],["2017-03-01",5.0],["2017-02-01",5.1],["2017-01-01",5.3],["2016-12-01",5.6],["2016-11-01",5.3],["2016-10-01",5.2],["2016-09-01",5.2],["2016-08-01",5.0],["2016-07-01",4.5],["2016-06-01",5.2],["2016-05-01",5.2],["2016-04-01",5.1],["2016-03-01",5.4],["2016-02-01",5.4],["2016-01-01",5.5],["2015-12-01",5.2],["2015-11-01",5.5],["2015-10-01",5.7],["2015-09-01",5.9],["2015-08-01",5.1],["2015-07-01",5.2],["2015-06-01",5.5],["2015-05-01",5.0],["2015-04-01",4.9],["2015-03-01",5.1],["2015-02-01",4.4],["2015-01-01",4.8],["2014-12-01",5.2],["2014-11-01",5.7],["2014-10-01",5.3],["2014-09-01",5.4],["2014-08-01",5.5],["2014-07-01",6.1],["2014-06-01",5.7],["2014-05-01",5.2],["2014-04-01",5.7],["2014-03-01",5.6],["2014-02-01",5.2],["2014-01-01",5.1],["2013-12-01",5.2],["2013-11-01",5.0],["2013-10-01",4.9],["2013-09-01",5.4],["2013-08-01",5.5],["2013-07-01",5.5],["2013-06-01",4.1],["2013-05-01",4.6],["2013-04-01",4.4],["2013-03-01",4.2],["2013-02-01",4.1],["2013-01-01",4.0],["2012-12-01",4.5],["2012-11-01",4.6],["2012-10-01",4.9],["2012-09-01",4.5],["2012-08-01",4.6],["2012-07-01",4.6],["2012-06-01",4.8],["2012-05-01",4.7],["2012-04-01",4.9],["2012-03-01",4.9],["2012-02-01",4.8],["2012-01-01",5.3],["2011-12-01",5.3],["2011-11-01",5.7],["2011-10-01",6.0],["2011-09-01",6.3],["2011-08-01",6.5],["2011-07-01",6.7],["2011-06-01",6.6],["2011-05-01",6.6],["2011-04-01",6.7],["2011-03-01",7.2],["2011-02-01",8.1],["2011-01-01",7.3],["2010-12-01",7.0],["2010-11-01",8.2],["2010-10-01",8.2],["2010-09-01",7.6],["2010-08-01",8.8],["2010-07-01",8.9],["2010-06-01",8.3],["2010-05-01",9.3],["2010-04-01",6.2],["2010-03-01",7.1],["2010-02-01",8.3],["2010-01-01",8.1],["2009-12-01",8.0],["2009-11-01",7.6],["2009-10-01",7.4],["2009-09-01",7.8],["2009-08-01",7.5],["2009-07-01",7.9],["2009-06-01",8.5],["2009-05-01",9.3],["2009-04-01",10.7],["2009-03-01",11.0],["2009-02-01",10.5],["2009-01-01",12.2],["2008-12-01",11.2],["2008-11-01",11.4],["2008-10-01",11.6],["2008-09-01",10.9],["2008-08-01",11.3],["2008-07-01",10.5],["2008-06-01",10.7],["2008-05-01",10.7],["2008-04-01",10.3],["2008-03-01",10.5],["2008-02-01",9.7],["2008-01-01",9.3],["2007-12-01",9.6],["2007-11-01",9.4],["2007-10-01",8.5],["2007-09-01",9.2],["2007-08-01",9.2],["2007-07-01",8.3],["2007-06-01",8.2],["2007-05-01",7.8],["2007-04-01",7.4],["2007-03-01",7.9],["2007-02-01",7.9],["2007-01-01",7.2],["2006-12-01",6.5],["2006-11-01",6.6],["2006-10-01",7.3],["2006-09-01",6.7],["2006-08-01",6.7],["2006-07-01",7.3],["2006-06-01",6.3],["2006-05-01",6.2],["2006-04-01",6.3],["2006-03-01",5.9],["2006-02-01",6.1],["2006-01-01",5.3],["2005-12-01",4.9],["2005-11-01",5.0],["2005-10-01",4.5],["2005-09-01",4.7],["2005-08-01",4.5],["2005-07-01",4.2],["2005-06-01",4.3],["2005-05-01",4.2],["2005-04-01",4.3],["2005-03-01",4.1],["2005-02-01",4.3],["2005-01-01",4.4],["2004-12-01",4.1],["2004-11-01",4.3],["2004-10-01",3.9],["2004-09-01",4.1],["2004-08-01",4.3],["2004-07-01",4.5],["2004-06-01",3.9],["2004-05-01",3.8],["2004-04-01",4.0],["2004-03-01",3.6],["2004-02-01",3.7],["2004-01-01",3.8],["2003-12-01",4.0],["2003-11-01",4.1],["2003-10-01",3.8],["2003-09-01",3.8],["2003-08-01",3.5],["2003-07-01",3.6],["2003-06-01",3.5],["2003-05-01",3.9],["2003-04-01",4.1],["2003-03-01",4.1],["2003-02-01",4.5],["2003-01-01",4.0],["2002-12-01",4.0],["2002-11-01",4.0],["2002-10-01",4.0],["2002-09-01",3.9],["2002-08-01",4.0],["2002-07-01",4.2],["2002-06-01",4.2],["2002-05-01",4.0],["2002-04-01",4.3],["2002-03-01",4.1],["2002-02-01",4.0],["2002-01-01",4.2],["2001-12-01",3.8],["2001-11-01",4.1],["2001-10-01",4.3],["2001-09-01",4.4],["2001-08-01",4.4],["2001-07-01",4.2],["2001-06-01",4.2],["2001-05-01",4.0],["2001-04-01",3.9],["2001-03-01",3.8],["2001-02-01",3.7],["2001-01-01",3.8],["2000-12-01",3.6],["2000-11-01",4.2],["2000-10-01",4.0],["2000-09-01",4.0],["2000-08-01",4.4],["2000-07-01",4.1],["2000-06-01",4.8],["2000-05-01",4.4],["2000-04-01",4.4],["2000-03-01",4.3],["2000-02-01",4.3],["2000-01-01",4.3],["1999-12-01",4.3],["1999-11-01",4.3],["1999-10-01",4.2],["1999-09-01",4.5],["1999-08-01",4.0],["1999-07-01",4.0],["1999-06-01",3.9],["1999-05-01",4.0],["1999-04-01",3.9],["1999-03-01",4.1],["1999-02-01",4.0],["1999-01-01",3.9],["1998-12-01",3.8],["1998-11-01",3.5],["1998-10-01",4.0],["1998-09-01",4.1],["1998-08-01",4.1],["1998-07-01",4.0],["1998-06-01",3.8],["1998-05-01",3.9],["1998-04-01",4.0],["1998-03-01",4.1],["1998-02-01",3.9],["1998-01-01",4.0],["1997-12-01",4.4],["1997-11-01",3.9],["1997-10-01",4.3],["1997-09-01",4.2],["1997-08-01",4.3],["1997-07-01",4.4],["1997-06-01",4.4],["1997-05-01",4.6],["1997-04-01",4.7],["1997-03-01",4.1],["1997-02-01",4.5],["1997-01-01",4.7],["1996-12-01",5.0],["1996-11-01",5.2],["1996-10-01",5.6],["1996-09-01",5.2],["1996-08-01",5.0],["1996-07-01",5.7],["1996-06-01",6.0],["1996-05-01",5.9],["1996-04-01",6.0],["1996-03-01",6.2],["1996-02-01",5.3],["1996-01-01",6.4],["1995-12-01",6.4],["1995-11-01",6.8],["1995-10-01",6.3],["1995-09-01",6.3],["1995-08-01",6.1],["1995-07-01",5.6],["1995-06-01",5.8],["1995-05-01",6.3],["1995-04-01",6.7],["1995-03-01",6.8],["1995-02-01",7.3],["1995-01-01",6.8],["1994-12-01",6.6],["1994-11-01",6.3],["1994-10-01",5.6],["1994-09-01",6.0],["1994-08-01",6.1],["1994-07-01",6.3],["1994-06-01",6.2],["1994-05-01",5.3],["1994-04-01",5.2],["1994-03-01",4.8],["1994-02-01",5.0],["1994-01-01",5.9],["1993-12-01",4.5],["1993-11-01",4.8],["1993-10-01",5.0],["1993-09-01",4.9],["1993-08-01",5.5],["1993-07-01",5.3],["1993-06-01",5.2],["1993-05-01",5.3],["1993-04-01",4.7],["1993-03-01",5.4],["1993-02-01",5.3],["1993-01-01",5.4],["1992-12-01",5.0],["1992-11-01",5.4],["1992-10-01",5.1],["1992-09-01",5.0],["1992-08-01",5.2],["1992-07-01",5.3],["1992-06-01",5.6],["1992-05-01",6.0],["1992-04-01",6.1],["1992-03-01",6.1],["1992-02-01",4.9],["1992-01-01",5.2],["1991-12-01",6.2],["1991-11-01",6.2],["1991-10-01",6.7],["1991-09-01",7.4],["1991-08-01",6.8],["1991-07-01",7.1],["1991-06-01",7.0],["1991-05-01",7.0],["1991-04-01",7.3],["1991-03-01",7.3],["1991-02-01",7.9],["1991-01-01",9.4],["1990-12-01",8.5],["1990-11-01",8.2],["1990-10-01",8.7],["1990-09-01",8.4],["1990-08-01",8.2],["1990-07-01",7.8],["1990-06-01",7.9],["1990-05-01",8.2],["1990-04-01",8.3],["1990-03-01",7.8],["1990-02-01",7.6],["1990-01-01",7.0],["1989-12-01",7.0],["1989-11-01",6.6],["1989-10-01",6.9],["1989-09-01",7.1],["1989-08-01",6.4],["1989-07-01",6.1],["1989-06-01",7.2],["1989-05-01",7.1],["1989-04-01",7.4],["1989-03-01",8.2],["1989-02-01",7.5],["1989-01-01",6.2],["1988-12-01",6.8],["1988-11-01",7.2],["1988-10-01",6.0],["1988-09-01",6.5],["1988-08-01",6.6],["1988-07-01",6.6],["1988-06-01",6.2],["1988-05-01",6.6],["1988-04-01",6.4],["1988-03-01",6.6],["1988-02-01",6.6],["1988-01-01",7.5],["1987-12-01",7.6],["1987-11-01",7.0],["1987-10-01",6.8],["1987-09-01",6.8],["1987-08-01",6.8],["1987-07-01",6.7],["1987-06-01",6.9],["1987-05-01",6.7],["1987-04-01",6.0],["1987-03-01",6.0],["1987-02-01",6.2],["1987-01-01",6.0],["1986-12-01",5.5],["1986-11-01",6.1],["1986-10-01",6.5],["1986-09-01",5.8],["1986-08-01",7.0],["1986-07-01",6.1],["1986-06-01",5.7],["1986-05-01",5.2],["1986-04-01",4.7],["1986-03-01",4.7],["1986-02-01",6.0],["1986-01-01",5.7],["1985-12-01",5.8],["1985-11-01",5.9],["1985-10-01",6.4],["1985-09-01",6.3],["1985-08-01",5.8],["1985-07-01",5.6],["1985-06-01",6.0],["1985-05-01",6.4],["1985-04-01",6.9],["1985-03-01",6.4],["1985-02-01",6.5],["1985-01-01",6.7],["1984-12-01",7.3],["1984-11-01",7.2],["1984-10-01",6.0],["1984-09-01",6.5],["1984-08-01",7.5],["1984-07-01",6.7],["1984-06-01",6.6],["1984-05-01",6.7],["1984-04-01",6.0],["1984-03-01",6.1],["1984-02-01",5.1],["1984-01-01",5.3],["1983-12-01",4.7],["1983-11-01",5.8],["1983-10-01",5.6],["1983-09-01",6.2],["1983-08-01",6.2],["1983-07-01",5.8],["1983-06-01",5.3],["1983-05-01",4.9],["1983-04-01",5.1],["1983-03-01",5.4],["1983-02-01",5.6],["1983-01-01",5.4],["1982-12-01",5.8],["1982-11-01",5.4],["1982-10-01",6.2],["1982-09-01",6.7],["1982-08-01",7.1],["1982-07-01",8.2],["1982-06-01",8.3],["1982-05-01",8.3],["1982-04-01",9.4],["1982-03-01",8.7],["1982-02-01",9.2],["1982-01-01",8.9],["1981-12-01",7.1],["1981-11-01",9.1],["1981-10-01",10.3],["1981-09-01",11.3],["1981-08-01",9.8],["1981-07-01",9.0],["1981-06-01",9.2],["1981-05-01",8.4],["1981-04-01",8.6],["1981-03-01",7.7],["1981-02-01",8.1],["1981-01-01",8.0],["1980-12-01",7.6],["1980-11-01",7.4],["1980-10-01",7.3],["1980-09-01",7.3],["1980-08-01",6.0],["1980-07-01",6.5],["1980-06-01",7.6],["1980-05-01",9.2],["1980-04-01",11.6],["1980-03-01",9.8],["1980-02-01",8.6],["1980-01-01",7.9],["1979-12-01",8.6],["1979-11-01",8.3],["1979-10-01",7.4],["1979-09-01",7.4],["1979-08-01",6.9],["1979-07-01",7.1],["1979-06-01",7.4],["1979-05-01",7.1],["1979-04-01",6.8],["1979-03-01",6.6],["1979-02-01",6.8],["1979-01-01",6.6],["1978-12-01",6.1],["1978-11-01",6.5],["1978-10-01",5.7],["1978-09-01",5.9],["1978-08-01",6.6],["1978-07-01",6.6],["1978-06-01",6.2],["1978-05-01",5.9],["1978-04-01",5.8],["1978-03-01",6.1],["1978-02-01",6.3],["1978-01-01",5.9],["1977-12-01",6.0],["1977-11-01",6.0],["1977-10-01",6.1],["1977-09-01",5.9],["1977-08-01",5.8],["1977-07-01",6.1],["1977-06-01",5.5],["1977-05-01",5.4],["1977-04-01",5.5],["1977-03-01",5.0],["1977-02-01",5.1],["1977-01-01",5.3],["1976-12-01",5.6],["1976-11-01",6.0],["1976-10-01",5.8],["1976-09-01",6.2],["1976-08-01",6.2],["1976-07-01",6.4],["1976-06-01",6.9],["1976-05-01",7.0],["1976-04-01",6.4],["1976-03-01",6.8],["1976-02-01",5.9],["1976-01-01",6.4],["1975-12-01",5.8],["1975-11-01",5.8],["1975-10-01",6.6],["1975-09-01",7.3],["1975-08-01",6.8],["1975-07-01",7.0],["1975-06-01",7.2],["1975-05-01",6.8],["1975-04-01",7.2],["1975-03-01",8.9],["1975-02-01",10.4],["1975-01-01",9.9],["1974-12-01",10.3],["1974-11-01",9.7],["1974-10-01",9.8],["1974-09-01",9.1],["1974-08-01",9.3],["1974-07-01",8.8],["1974-06-01",8.9],["1974-05-01",8.0],["1974-04-01",9.1],["1974-03-01",8.8],["1974-02-01",9.6],["1974-01-01",9.7],["1973-12-01",10.1],["1973-11-01",9.6],["1973-10-01",9.4],["1973-09-01",9.5],["1973-08-01",9.4],["1973-07-01",8.7],["1973-06-01",7.8],["1973-05-01",7.5],["1973-04-01",7.7],["1973-03-01",7.0],["1973-02-01",6.8],["1973-01-01",6.5],["1972-12-01",6.5],["1972-11-01",6.8],["1972-10-01",5.7],["1972-09-01",6.2],["1972-08-01",6.0],["1972-07-01",6.3],["1972-06-01",6.3],["1972-05-01",6.1],["1972-04-01",5.8],["1972-03-01",6.1],["1972-02-01",5.4],["1972-01-01",5.2],["1971-12-01",5.1],["1971-11-01",4.9],["1971-10-01",5.0],["1971-09-01",5.2],["1971-08-01",4.7],["1971-07-01",4.1],["1971-06-01",4.7],["1971-05-01",4.6],["1971-04-01",4.2],["1971-03-01",4.0],["1971-02-01",4.4],["1971-01-01",4.3],["1970-12-01",4.7],["1970-11-01",4.6],["1970-10-01",4.8],["1970-09-01",4.7],["1970-08-01",5.1],["1970-07-01",5.4],["1970-06-01",5.5],["1970-05-01",5.7],["1970-04-01",6.0],["1970-03-01",6.8],["1970-02-01",7.2],["1970-01-01",5.5],["1969-12-01",6.1],["1969-11-01",6.2],["1969-10-01",7.0],["1969-09-01",6.9],["1969-08-01",6.5],["1969-07-01",6.3],["1969-06-01",5.8],["1969-05-01",6.1],["1969-04-01",6.0],["1969-03-01",5.7],["1969-02-01",4.9],["1969-01-01",5.5],["1968-12-01",5.2],["1968-11-01",5.6],["1968-10-01",5.2],["1968-09-01",5.1],["1968-08-01",5.0],["1968-07-01",5.1],["1968-06-01",5.5],["1968-05-01",5.5],["1968-04-01",4.9],["1968-03-01",4.8],["1968-02-01",4.1],["1968-01-01",4.7],["1967-12-01",4.7],["1967-11-01",4.6],["1967-10-01",4.1],["1967-09-01",4.3],["1967-08-01",4.4],["1967-07-01",4.4],["1967-06-01",4.6],["1967-05-01",4.5],["1967-04-01",4.9],["1967-03-01",5.4],["1967-02-01",5.7],["1967-01-01",5.7],["1966-12-01",6.3],["1966-11-01",6.2],["1966-10-01",6.3],["1966-09-01",7.2],["1966-08-01",6.8],["1966-07-01",5.9],["1966-06-01",6.0],["1966-05-01",5.3],["1966-04-01",5.1],["1966-03-01",5.0],["1966-02-01",4.9],["1966-01-01",4.7],["1965-12-01",4.4],["1965-11-01",4.6],["1965-10-01",5.0],["1965-09-01",4.9],["1965-08-01",4.6],["1965-07-01",5.2],["1965-06-01",4.7],["1965-05-01",5.3],["1965-04-01",5.6],["1965-03-01",5.4],["1965-02-01",5.5],["1965-01-01",5.6],["1964-12-01",5.5],["1964-11-01",5.6],["1964-10-01",5.3],["1964-09-01",5.4],["1964-08-01",5.4],["1964-07-01",5.5],["1964-06-01",5.7],["1964-05-01",6.2],["1964-04-01",6.0],["1964-03-01",5.8],["1964-02-01",5.5],["1964-01-01",5.8],["1963-12-01",6.1],["1963-11-01",5.5],["1963-10-01",5.9],["1963-09-01",5.4],["1963-08-01",5.6],["1963-07-01",4.6],["1963-06-01",6.0],["1963-05-01",5.1],["1963-04-01",5.3],["1963-03-01",6.4],["1963-02-01",6.6],["1963-01-01",4.7]],"collapse":null,"order":null,"database_id":118}}

var totalSum = '0';
$.each(results.dataset.data, function(key, value){
  totalSum += parseFloat(value[1]);
});
console.log("Total Sum: "+totalSum);
```

The above does not sum the values but it adds them together into a single long string. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Side note, The second value of the data elements is already a number, so trying to parseFloat is not necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial value of `totalSum` is string. Thus `+=` is doing the string concatenation. To perform the arithmetic operation, change the initial value to number (`0`).

Change

```
var totalSum = '0';
```

To

```
var totalSum = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

`totalSum` should be a numeric, not a string. Remove the quotes surrounding the `0`.

```
var totalSum = 0;
$.each(results.dataset.data, function(key, value){
        totalSum += parseFloat(value[1]);
});
```

The `+` operator will perform string concatenation if one of the operands is a string. It will only perform numeric addition if both operands are numeric.

Answer (score 1):

Change `totalSum = '0'` to `totalSum = 0`

> The addition assignment operator adds the value of the right operand to a variable and assigns the result to the variable. **The types of the two operands determine the behavior of the addition assignment operator**.
>
> The addition operator(**+**) produces the **sum of numeric operands** or **string concatenation**.
>
> > Number + Number -> addition **(ex. 1 + 2 = 3)**
> >
> > Boolean + Number -> addition **(ex.true + 1 = 2)**
> >
> > Boolean + Boolean -> addition **(ex.false + false = 0)**
> >
> > Number + String -> concatenation **(ex.5 + 'foo' = "5foo")**
> >
> > String + Boolean -> concatenation **('foo' + false + "foofalse")**
> >
> > String + String -> concatenation **('foo' + 'bar' = "foobar")**

```js
var results=  {"dataset":{"id":123643,"dataset_code":"MSACSR","database_code":"FRED","name":"Monthly Supply of Houses in the United States","description":"Months' Supply Seasonally Adjusted, The months' supply is the ratio of houses for sale to houses sold. This statistic provides an indication of the size of the for sale inventory in relation to the number of houses currently being sold. The months' supply indicates how long  the current for sale inventory would last given the current sales rate if no additional new houses were built. ","refreshed_at":"2018-07-29T02:49:52.644Z","newest_available_date":"2018-06-01","oldest_available_date":"1963-01-01","column_names":["Date","Value"],"frequency":"monthly","type":"Time Series","premium":false,"limit":null,"transform":null,"column_index":null,"start_date":"1963-01-01","end_date":"2018-06-01","data":[["2018-06-01",5.7],["2018-05-01",5.3],["2018-04-01",5.6],["2018-03-01",5.3],["2018-02-01",5.4],["2018-01-01",5.6],["2017-12-01",5.5],["2017-11-01",4.9],["2017-10-01",5.6],["2017-09-01",5.3],["2017-08-01",6.0],["2017-07-01",6.0],["2017-06-01",5.3],["2017-05-01",5.4],["2017-04-01",5.4],["2017-03-01",5.0],["2017-02-01",5.1],["2017-01-01",5.3],["2016-12-01",5.6],["2016-11-01",5.3],["2016-10-01",5.2],["2016-09-01",5.2],["2016-08-01",5.0],["2016-07-01",4.5],["2016-06-01",5.2],["2016-05-01",5.2],["2016-04-01",5.1],["2016-03-01",5.4],["2016-02-01",5.4],["2016-01-01",5.5],["2015-12-01",5.2],["2015-11-01",5.5],["2015-10-01",5.7],["2015-09-01",5.9],["2015-08-01",5.1],["2015-07-01",5.2],["2015-06-01",5.5],["2015-05-01",5.0],["2015-04-01",4.9],["2015-03-01",5.1],["2015-02-01",4.4],["2015-01-01",4.8],["2014-12-01",5.2],["2014-11-01",5.7],["2014-10-01",5.3],["2014-09-01",5.4],["2014-08-01",5.5],["2014-07-01",6.1],["2014-06-01",5.7],["2014-05-01",5.2],["2014-04-01",5.7],["2014-03-01",5.6],["2014-02-01",5.2],["2014-01-01",5.1],["2013-12-01",5.2],["2013-11-01",5.0],["2013-10-01",4.9],["2013-09-01",5.4],["2013-08-01",5.5],["2013-07-01",5.5],["2013-06-01",4.1],["2013-05-01",4.6],["2013-04-01",4.4],["2013-03-01",4.2],["2013-02-01",4.1],["2013-01-01",4.0],["2012-12-01",4.5],["2012-11-01",4.6],["2012-10-01",4.9],["2012-09-01",4.5],["2012-08-01",4.6],["2012-07-01",4.6],["2012-06-01",4.8],["2012-05-01",4.7],["2012-04-01",4.9],["2012-03-01",4.9],["2012-02-01",4.8],["2012-01-01",5.3],["2011-12-01",5.3],["2011-11-01",5.7],["2011-10-01",6.0],["2011-09-01",6.3],["2011-08-01",6.5],["2011-07-01",6.7],["2011-06-01",6.6],["2011-05-01",6.6],["2011-04-01",6.7],["2011-03-01",7.2],["2011-02-01",8.1],["2011-01-01",7.3],["2010-12-01",7.0],["2010-11-01",8.2],["2010-10-01",8.2],["2010-09-01",7.6],["2010-08-01",8.8],["2010-07-01",8.9],["2010-06-01",8.3],["2010-05-01",9.3],["2010-04-01",6.2],["2010-03-01",7.1],["2010-02-01",8.3],["2010-01-01",8.1],["2009-12-01",8.0],["2009-11-01",7.6],["2009-10-01",7.4],["2009-09-01",7.8],["2009-08-01",7.5],["2009-07-01",7.9],["2009-06-01",8.5],["2009-05-01",9.3],["2009-04-01",10.7],["2009-03-01",11.0],["2009-02-01",10.5],["2009-01-01",12.2],["2008-12-01",11.2],["2008-11-01",11.4],["2008-10-01",11.6],["2008-09-01",10.9],["2008-08-01",11.3],["2008-07-01",10.5],["2008-06-01",10.7],["2008-05-01",10.7],["2008-04-01",10.3],["2008-03-01",10.5],["2008-02-01",9.7],["2008-01-01",9.3],["2007-12-01",9.6],["2007-11-01",9.4],["2007-10-01",8.5],["2007-09-01",9.2],["2007-08-01",9.2],["2007-07-01",8.3],["2007-06-01",8.2],["2007-05-01",7.8],["2007-04-01",7.4],["2007-03-01",7.9],["2007-02-01",7.9],["2007-01-01",7.2],["2006-12-01",6.5],["2006-11-01",6.6],["2006-10-01",7.3],["2006-09-01",6.7],["2006-08-01",6.7],["2006-07-01",7.3],["2006-06-01",6.3],["2006-05-01",6.2],["2006-04-01",6.3],["2006-03-01",5.9],["2006-02-01",6.1],["2006-01-01",5.3],["2005-12-01",4.9],["2005-11-01",5.0],["2005-10-01",4.5],["2005-09-01",4.7],["2005-08-01",4.5],["2005-07-01",4.2],["2005-06-01",4.3],["2005-05-01",4.2],["2005-04-01",4.3],["2005-03-01",4.1],["2005-02-01",4.3],["2005-01-01",4.4],["2004-12-01",4.1],["2004-11-01",4.3],["2004-10-01",3.9],["2004-09-01",4.1],["2004-08-01",4.3],["2004-07-01",4.5],["2004-06-01",3.9],["2004-05-01",3.8],["2004-04-01",4.0],["2004-03-01",3.6],["2004-02-01",3.7],["2004-01-01",3.8],["2003-12-01",4.0],["2003-11-01",4.1],["2003-10-01",3.8],["2003-09-01",3.8],["2003-08-01",3.5],["2003-07-01",3.6],["2003-06-01",3.5],["2003-05-01",3.9],["2003-04-01",4.1],["2003-03-01",4.1],["2003-02-01",4.5],["2003-01-01",4.0],["2002-12-01",4.0],["2002-11-01",4.0],["2002-10-01",4.0],["2002-09-01",3.9],["2002-08-01",4.0],["2002-07-01",4.2],["2002-06-01",4.2],["2002-05-01",4.0],["2002-04-01",4.3],["2002-03-01",4.1],["2002-02-01",4.0],["2002-01-01",4.2],["2001-12-01",3.8],["2001-11-01",4.1],["2001-10-01",4.3],["2001-09-01",4.4],["2001-08-01",4.4],["2001-07-01",4.2],["2001-06-01",4.2],["2001-05-01",4.0],["2001-04-01",3.9],["2001-03-01",3.8],["2001-02-01",3.7],["2001-01-01",3.8],["2000-12-01",3.6],["2000-11-01",4.2],["2000-10-01",4.0],["2000-09-01",4.0],["2000-08-01",4.4],["2000-07-01",4.1],["2000-06-01",4.8],["2000-05-01",4.4],["2000-04-01",4.4],["2000-03-01",4.3],["2000-02-01",4.3],["2000-01-01",4.3],["1999-12-01",4.3],["1999-11-01",4.3],["1999-10-01",4.2],["1999-09-01",4.5],["1999-08-01",4.0],["1999-07-01",4.0],["1999-06-01",3.9],["1999-05-01",4.0],["1999-04-01",3.9],["1999-03-01",4.1],["1999-02-01",4.0],["1999-01-01",3.9],["1998-12-01",3.8],["1998-11-01",3.5],["1998-10-01",4.0],["1998-09-01",4.1],["1998-08-01",4.1],["1998-07-01",4.0],["1998-06-01",3.8],["1998-05-01",3.9],["1998-04-01",4.0],["1998-03-01",4.1],["1998-02-01",3.9],["1998-01-01",4.0],["1997-12-01",4.4],["1997-11-01",3.9],["1997-10-01",4.3],["1997-09-01",4.2],["1997-08-01",4.3],["1997-07-01",4.4],["1997-06-01",4.4],["1997-05-01",4.6],["1997-04-01",4.7],["1997-03-01",4.1],["1997-02-01",4.5],["1997-01-01",4.7],["1996-12-01",5.0],["1996-11-01",5.2],["1996-10-01",5.6],["1996-09-01",5.2],["1996-08-01",5.0],["1996-07-01",5.7],["1996-06-01",6.0],["1996-05-01",5.9],["1996-04-01",6.0],["1996-03-01",6.2],["1996-02-01",5.3],["1996-01-01",6.4],["1995-12-01",6.4],["1995-11-01",6.8],["1995-10-01",6.3],["1995-09-01",6.3],["1995-08-01",6.1],["1995-07-01",5.6],["1995-06-01",5.8],["1995-05-01",6.3],["1995-04-01",6.7],["1995-03-01",6.8],["1995-02-01",7.3],["1995-01-01",6.8],["1994-12-01",6.6],["1994-11-01",6.3],["1994-10-01",5.6],["1994-09-01",6.0],["1994-08-01",6.1],["1994-07-01",6.3],["1994-06-01",6.2],["1994-05-01",5.3],["1994-04-01",5.2],["1994-03-01",4.8],["1994-02-01",5.0],["1994-01-01",5.9],["1993-12-01",4.5],["1993-11-01",4.8],["1993-10-01",5.0],["1993-09-01",4.9],["1993-08-01",5.5],["1993-07-01",5.3],["1993-06-01",5.2],["1993-05-01",5.3],["1993-04-01",4.7],["1993-03-01",5.4],["1993-02-01",5.3],["1993-01-01",5.4],["1992-12-01",5.0],["1992-11-01",5.4],["1992-10-01",5.1],["1992-09-01",5.0],["1992-08-01",5.2],["1992-07-01",5.3],["1992-06-01",5.6],["1992-05-01",6.0],["1992-04-01",6.1],["1992-03-01",6.1],["1992-02-01",4.9],["1992-01-01",5.2],["1991-12-01",6.2],["1991-11-01",6.2],["1991-10-01",6.7],["1991-09-01",7.4],["1991-08-01",6.8],["1991-07-01",7.1],["1991-06-01",7.0],["1991-05-01",7.0],["1991-04-01",7.3],["1991-03-01",7.3],["1991-02-01",7.9],["1991-01-01",9.4],["1990-12-01",8.5],["1990-11-01",8.2],["1990-10-01",8.7],["1990-09-01",8.4],["1990-08-01",8.2],["1990-07-01",7.8],["1990-06-01",7.9],["1990-05-01",8.2],["1990-04-01",8.3],["1990-03-01",7.8],["1990-02-01",7.6],["1990-01-01",7.0],["1989-12-01",7.0],["1989-11-01",6.6],["1989-10-01",6.9],["1989-09-01",7.1],["1989-08-01",6.4],["1989-07-01",6.1],["1989-06-01",7.2],["1989-05-01",7.1],["1989-04-01",7.4],["1989-03-01",8.2],["1989-02-01",7.5],["1989-01-01",6.2],["1988-12-01",6.8],["1988-11-01",7.2],["1988-10-01",6.0],["1988-09-01",6.5],["1988-08-01",6.6],["1988-07-01",6.6],["1988-06-01",6.2],["1988-05-01",6.6],["1988-04-01",6.4],["1988-03-01",6.6],["1988-02-01",6.6],["1988-01-01",7.5],["1987-12-01",7.6],["1987-11-01",7.0],["1987-10-01",6.8],["1987-09-01",6.8],["1987-08-01",6.8],["1987-07-01",6.7],["1987-06-01",6.9],["1987-05-01",6.7],["1987-04-01",6.0],["1987-03-01",6.0],["1987-02-01",6.2],["1987-01-01",6.0],["1986-12-01",5.5],["1986-11-01",6.1],["1986-10-01",6.5],["1986-09-01",5.8],["1986-08-01",7.0],["1986-07-01",6.1],["1986-06-01",5.7],["1986-05-01",5.2],["1986-04-01",4.7],["1986-03-01",4.7],["1986-02-01",6.0],["1986-01-01",5.7],["1985-12-01",5.8],["1985-11-01",5.9],["1985-10-01",6.4],["1985-09-01",6.3],["1985-08-01",5.8],["1985-07-01",5.6],["1985-06-01",6.0],["1985-05-01",6.4],["1985-04-01",6.9],["1985-03-01",6.4],["1985-02-01",6.5],["1985-01-01",6.7],["1984-12-01",7.3],["1984-11-01",7.2],["1984-10-01",6.0],["1984-09-01",6.5],["1984-08-01",7.5],["1984-07-01",6.7],["1984-06-01",6.6],["1984-05-01",6.7],["1984-04-01",6.0],["1984-03-01",6.1],["1984-02-01",5.1],["1984-01-01",5.3],["1983-12-01",4.7],["1983-11-01",5.8],["1983-10-01",5.6],["1983-09-01",6.2],["1983-08-01",6.2],["1983-07-01",5.8],["1983-06-01",5.3],["1983-05-01",4.9],["1983-04-01",5.1],["1983-03-01",5.4],["1983-02-01",5.6],["1983-01-01",5.4],["1982-12-01",5.8],["1982-11-01",5.4],["1982-10-01",6.2],["1982-09-01",6.7],["1982-08-01",7.1],["1982-07-01",8.2],["1982-06-01",8.3],["1982-05-01",8.3],["1982-04-01",9.4],["1982-03-01",8.7],["1982-02-01",9.2],["1982-01-01",8.9],["1981-12-01",7.1],["1981-11-01",9.1],["1981-10-01",10.3],["1981-09-01",11.3],["1981-08-01",9.8],["1981-07-01",9.0],["1981-06-01",9.2],["1981-05-01",8.4],["1981-04-01",8.6],["1981-03-01",7.7],["1981-02-01",8.1],["1981-01-01",8.0],["1980-12-01",7.6],["1980-11-01",7.4],["1980-10-01",7.3],["1980-09-01",7.3],["1980-08-01",6.0],["1980-07-01",6.5],["1980-06-01",7.6],["1980-05-01",9.2],["1980-04-01",11.6],["1980-03-01",9.8],["1980-02-01",8.6],["1980-01-01",7.9],["1979-12-01",8.6],["1979-11-01",8.3],["1979-10-01",7.4],["1979-09-01",7.4],["1979-08-01",6.9],["1979-07-01",7.1],["1979-06-01",7.4],["1979-05-01",7.1],["1979-04-01",6.8],["1979-03-01",6.6],["1979-02-01",6.8],["1979-01-01",6.6],["1978-12-01",6.1],["1978-11-01",6.5],["1978-10-01",5.7],["1978-09-01",5.9],["1978-08-01",6.6],["1978-07-01",6.6],["1978-06-01",6.2],["1978-05-01",5.9],["1978-04-01",5.8],["1978-03-01",6.1],["1978-02-01",6.3],["1978-01-01",5.9],["1977-12-01",6.0],["1977-11-01",6.0],["1977-10-01",6.1],["1977-09-01",5.9],["1977-08-01",5.8],["1977-07-01",6.1],["1977-06-01",5.5],["1977-05-01",5.4],["1977-04-01",5.5],["1977-03-01",5.0],["1977-02-01",5.1],["1977-01-01",5.3],["1976-12-01",5.6],["1976-11-01",6.0],["1976-10-01",5.8],["1976-09-01",6.2],["1976-08-01",6.2],["1976-07-01",6.4],["1976-06-01",6.9],["1976-05-01",7.0],["1976-04-01",6.4],["1976-03-01",6.8],["1976-02-01",5.9],["1976-01-01",6.4],["1975-12-01",5.8],["1975-11-01",5.8],["1975-10-01",6.6],["1975-09-01",7.3],["1975-08-01",6.8],["1975-07-01",7.0],["1975-06-01",7.2],["1975-05-01",6.8],["1975-04-01",7.2],["1975-03-01",8.9],["1975-02-01",10.4],["1975-01-01",9.9],["1974-12-01",10.3],["1974-11-01",9.7],["1974-10-01",9.8],["1974-09-01",9.1],["1974-08-01",9.3],["1974-07-01",8.8],["1974-06-01",8.9],["1974-05-01",8.0],["1974-04-01",9.1],["1974-03-01",8.8],["1974-02-01",9.6],["1974-01-01",9.7],["1973-12-01",10.1],["1973-11-01",9.6],["1973-10-01",9.4],["1973-09-01",9.5],["1973-08-01",9.4],["1973-07-01",8.7],["1973-06-01",7.8],["1973-05-01",7.5],["1973-04-01",7.7],["1973-03-01",7.0],["1973-02-01",6.8],["1973-01-01",6.5],["1972-12-01",6.5],["1972-11-01",6.8],["1972-10-01",5.7],["1972-09-01",6.2],["1972-08-01",6.0],["1972-07-01",6.3],["1972-06-01",6.3],["1972-05-01",6.1],["1972-04-01",5.8],["1972-03-01",6.1],["1972-02-01",5.4],["1972-01-01",5.2],["1971-12-01",5.1],["1971-11-01",4.9],["1971-10-01",5.0],["1971-09-01",5.2],["1971-08-01",4.7],["1971-07-01",4.1],["1971-06-01",4.7],["1971-05-01",4.6],["1971-04-01",4.2],["1971-03-01",4.0],["1971-02-01",4.4],["1971-01-01",4.3],["1970-12-01",4.7],["1970-11-01",4.6],["1970-10-01",4.8],["1970-09-01",4.7],["1970-08-01",5.1],["1970-07-01",5.4],["1970-06-01",5.5],["1970-05-01",5.7],["1970-04-01",6.0],["1970-03-01",6.8],["1970-02-01",7.2],["1970-01-01",5.5],["1969-12-01",6.1],["1969-11-01",6.2],["1969-10-01",7.0],["1969-09-01",6.9],["1969-08-01",6.5],["1969-07-01",6.3],["1969-06-01",5.8],["1969-05-01",6.1],["1969-04-01",6.0],["1969-03-01",5.7],["1969-02-01",4.9],["1969-01-01",5.5],["1968-12-01",5.2],["1968-11-01",5.6],["1968-10-01",5.2],["1968-09-01",5.1],["1968-08-01",5.0],["1968-07-01",5.1],["1968-06-01",5.5],["1968-05-01",5.5],["1968-04-01",4.9],["1968-03-01",4.8],["1968-02-01",4.1],["1968-01-01",4.7],["1967-12-01",4.7],["1967-11-01",4.6],["1967-10-01",4.1],["1967-09-01",4.3],["1967-08-01",4.4],["1967-07-01",4.4],["1967-06-01",4.6],["1967-05-01",4.5],["1967-04-01",4.9],["1967-03-01",5.4],["1967-02-01",5.7],["1967-01-01",5.7],["1966-12-01",6.3],["1966-11-01",6.2],["1966-10-01",6.3],["1966-09-01",7.2],["1966-08-01",6.8],["1966-07-01",5.9],["1966-06-01",6.0],["1966-05-01",5.3],["1966-04-01",5.1],["1966-03-01",5.0],["1966-02-01",4.9],["1966-01-01",4.7],["1965-12-01",4.4],["1965-11-01",4.6],["1965-10-01",5.0],["1965-09-01",4.9],["1965-08-01",4.6],["1965-07-01",5.2],["1965-06-01",4.7],["1965-05-01",5.3],["1965-04-01",5.6],["1965-03-01",5.4],["1965-02-01",5.5],["1965-01-01",5.6],["1964-12-01",5.5],["1964-11-01",5.6],["1964-10-01",5.3],["1964-09-01",5.4],["1964-08-01",5.4],["1964-07-01",5.5],["1964-06-01",5.7],["1964-05-01",6.2],["1964-04-01",6.0],["1964-03-01",5.8],["1964-02-01",5.5],["1964-01-01",5.8],["1963-12-01",6.1],["1963-11-01",5.5],["1963-10-01",5.9],["1963-09-01",5.4],["1963-08-01",5.6],["1963-07-01",4.6],["1963-06-01",6.0],["1963-05-01",5.1],["1963-04-01",5.3],["1963-03-01",6.4],["1963-02-01",6.6],["1963-01-01",4.7]],"collapse":null,"order":null,"database_id":118}}

    var totalSum = 0;
    $.each(results.dataset.data, function(key, value){
            totalSum += parseFloat(value[1]);
    });
    console.log("Total Sum: "+totalSum);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```